# Adding a sale condition to a new mortgage

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom

I live in the UK and am currently looking to buy a house with my partner. The property will be about £230k towards which I will be supplying a £100k deposit and my partner zero deposit. For this reason I would like some kind of rider to exist on the property such that in the event of a sale of the property the first £100k of any money raised is mine. Is this possible and how could I go about it? Do any other similar solutions exist?

My concern is that if something should happen to her but not me perhaps some member of her family may try and make a claim on the property as part of her estate.

Comment: If you know how much you both are contributing, can't the ownership can be put in as that much percentage. A laywer should be able to help you.

Comment: I don't know, can it?

Comment: This really is a legal question and I am voting to close. Unmarried persons can choose to hold assets as _tenants in common_ with specified percentages of ownership in the property, so look into that. However, your partner's estate would then own the specified fraction of the property.

Comment: I believe this query is about "Personal investing and asset allocation" as per http://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. I didn't see anything there or in further pages about "legal" being OT.

Comment: Get a solicitor pronto. You shouldn't be asking such questions here on this forum because your question is a legal advice of specific type, and no one is a solicitor out here.

Comment: DC - yes, he needs a solicitor. I think it a good question, if only because I think my answer adds value to the discussion. Often, an OP needs help to know how to prepare for a meeting, I think the comments and my answer did that. He's better off for our advice.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - He doesn't even need to put a deposit of £100k. Under the government's help to buy scheme he can just put down a 5% deposit and the government will insure the 15% of the mortgage i.e. as if you put down a 20% deposit. If he goes under that scheme he needn't put up that much deposit also.

Comment: DC - Fair enough, and a good question back to the OP. I try not to question one's premise, but take the facts as presented. I imagined for whatever reason, the partner can only support the 65K mortgage, and Op decided to put a high deposit vs taking on the disproportionate loan value. Using your observation, he still has a value imbalance, and needs to account for that. Paul - DC's comment is really a question for you.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - My only reason to add that was, if he is so circumspect about his partner's relatives, he should be using the help to buy option offered by the government rather than putting down his own deposit. I would assume he is putting down a high deposit to get a cheaper mortgage rate or to be sure of his mortgage being approved.

Comment: DC - understood. Great advice, and a reason I shouldn't always accept a scenario as given. Your suggestion might save him from a bad deal.

Comment: Having looked into the tenants in common idea this appears to be the solution. Good article here: http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/news/article-1594984/Tenants-common.html. E.g. for me putting £100k into a £230k property you might say I have a share of 71.7% (100k+(230k/2) / 230k). This also addresses the idea I'd be getting no return (don't forget if house prices go down then getting the "first 100k" would have been a bonus!). Obviously a solicitor will be used in the house conveyance and this portion of dealings also. I just needed to know the concept I needed to engage.

Comment: @DumbCoder you may as well say no one is a "financial advisor here". I didn't see anything in the Help section about legal matters being OT. It's still about personal finance anyway.

Comment: @Paul - Ia m not sure why was the comment directed towards me. I never mentioned anything about OT.

Comment: @Paul: if your primary concern is who inherits the property if one of dies, joint tenancy, not tenancy-in-common may be better. With the former, you both own the whole property, so if one owner dies, the other continues to own the whole property; no part of it goes to the deceased's estate.

Comment: @Paul: if you do go for t-i-c, **update your wills**. A declaration of trust will protect your respective shares, but if you're not married and don't have wills, the deceased's share could go to their family, not to the partner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dilip Sarwate mentioned tenants in common in a comment. This appears to be in fact the answer I required. I found a friendly article on it here: http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/news/article-1594984/Tenants-common.html. This appears to allow me to have a percentage based amount of the property, e.g.

£100k deposit, plus half of remainder (130k halved) means I own £165k on the initial £230k value of the property, i.e. 71.7% of the property. I will be asking the conveyancing solicitor if they are able to enact this.

Answer (score 4):

The Solicitor involved up front should be able to place constrictions as your suggesting.

I think you should look carefully at the desired wording. You deserve a return on your £100k. Say, the day after you buy (this is hypothetical, please bear with me) a developer says he needs the property and will give you £460k. Your wording here says you get £100k, and then, after the mortgage split £230k, but it seems more reasonable that your deposit doubles to £200k, the remaining £260k pays the mortgage, and the £130k left is split, £65k each.

My method accounts for the value of your £100k. Some would ask, why not apply the mortgage rate to that deposit? Because the home value may grow at a different rate. In my opinion, it's fair to apply the home value growth to the £100k deposit.

"Fair" means different things to different people. This is my opinion, and a suggestion. Consider it, and do what you and your partner wish. Use a solicitor. Put it in writing.

Comment: Or if the property values decrease I would have been better off with a "first £100k" idea :)

Comment: The downvote is curious to me. My answer is that OP should get a return on his 100K, else in 30 years, he and the partner see the same gain, but OP just lost decades of return on his deposit. Is there an opinion that this is wrong?

Comment: It's not an answer to the question it's just a vague idea that something should happen with no suggestion as to the mechanism.

Comment: Fair enough, although the math in your answer seems to have adopted my proposal vs the math in your question. Either way, welcome to Money.SE, I wish you well.

Comment: I'm sorry @JoeTaxpayer but I don't consider your answer an Answer. The self answer I posted mentions a mechanism that happens to work in that way. Like I commented (but you ignored) both idealogies of split have pros and cons. I wasn't entirely concerned with the idealogy but with what mechanism actually existed that I could use. I thought this clear in the original question when stated as "Is this possible and how could I go about it?".

Comment: @Paul. I understand, and am sorry I didn't add anything of value in responding to your question.